# How to Install Wordpress in a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, installation

I am trying to install wordpress in a subfolder - [www.anst.hr/wordpress](http://www.anst.hr/wordpress).

I uploaded FRESH wordpress files into my html folder via filezilla. Search [www.anst.hr/wordpress](http://www.anst.hr/wordpress) and I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in home/www/web2526/html/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2872
```

Then I renamed wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php and then got a different error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /home/www/web2526/html/wordpress/wp-includes/pomo/entry.php on line 61
```

Comment: on the line 17 on index.php change this path `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );` to `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Comment: That just caused;   
   Fatal error: main() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/www/web2526/html/wordpresswordpress/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/www/web2526/html/wordpress/index.php on line 17

And more errors I can't fit into this comment.

Comment: sorry it was missing a "/" `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Comment: tnx, but I get the same wp-blog-header error again :(